# Rust in bath, dishwasher, etc

Tags: plumbing

We have a house with old metal pipes (cast iron, copper) and we get rust in our dishwasher and bathtubs.

I want to replace the water heater (it's very old) and also replace the metal plumbing with Pex, but I'm wondering which one of these would get us to a "rust free" state faster?

Should I do the water heater first? or the Pex replacement in key areas?

Comment: I suggest finding out where the iron is coming from first; city water ? well water ?

Comment: it's city @blacksmith37

Comment: Do your neighbors have the same problem?

Comment: @JACK no my next door neighbor doesn't have this problem. The water heater and pipes are old, and when I increase the water pressure, more rust comes out. When I say "more rust" I don't mean "more water and rust" I mean the water has much more rust in it.

Comment: Neither case will get you rust free! If on well water go look at your well casing, if on city water the water tank is probably steel and much of the mains, I have had this complaint with copper plumbed homes on both city water and well water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that the rust is coming from the Water Heater. Not knowing the particulars of the WH, nearly all of them have the hot water outlet at the top of the tank. It would take a lot of usage volume to stir up the rust enough to flow out the top.

Most likely is you have galvanized pipe (iron/steel) that is rusting internally.  This often results in reduced flow because the rust in the pipe takes more volume than the original amount of steel (think like clogged arteries).

EDIT:  Meant to add:  Most all WH's have a drain valve at the bottom, hook up a hose turn  it on and see what comes out. That will help inform your decision about whether to replace or not.

Since you are going to do both anyway, I'd replace the piping first.  Who knows about the WH?  It could last another 10 years. My attitude toward water heaters is "run till failure".  Some rust out after 10-15 years, others much longer.  I have a rental house where the WH is 40 years old (electric) and is still going strong.

Answer (score 0):

At minimum replace the cold line which feeds the hot water tank so that you're not sending your new tank to an early grave.

As for becoming rust-free, you'll have to replace all of your non-copper lines.

I sincerely hope that "cast iron" is a typo because it should be galvanized steel.